# Regex Notepad++ - add quotes around timestamp

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many records in the format : 1900-01-03 00:00:00

I want to modify all of them to '1900-01-03 00:00:00'

I saw some posts on regex and tried some combinations but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what was that you tried? All you actually need is `\d` (or `[0-9]`) to get you started. Also, see http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Notepad++ (Press Ctrl + H)**

**Then search it:**

```
\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+
```

**and replace by**

```
'$0'
```

*This adds simple quotes*

**Original Text**

```
1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-03 00:00:00
1900-01-03 00:00:00
```

**Result**

```
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
'1900-01-03 00:00:00'
```

Comment: You did help me, thank you sir.

Comment: The `-` and `:`s don't need to be escaped (if the `-` were in a character class and wasn't the first/last character it would need to be escaped). Could just be `\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each record is on a new line and there aren't other values on the same row, you could use:

Find what: `^(.+)$` 
Replace with: `'$1'`

Under Search Mode make sure Regular expression is selected.

Comment: Careful, this will capture blanks

Comment: Good point. Edited to require at least one character on the line.